# how to skip a record which doesn't have a node in xsl.?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is my XML:

```
    <node>
      <siraj>abc</siraj>
      <shaik>ab</shaik>
      <basha>si</basha>
    </node>
    <node>
      <siraj>abc</siraj>
      <shaik>ab</shaik>
      <basha>si</basha>
    </node>
    <node>
      <siraj>abc</siraj>
      <basha>si</basha>
    </node>
    <node>
      <siraj>abc</siraj>
      <shaik>ab</shaik>
      <basha>si</basha>
    </node>
    <node>
      <siraj>abc</siraj>
      <basha>si</basha>
    </node>
```

And the XSLT:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//node">
    <xsl:if test="not(node/shaik)">
    <xsl:value-of select="siraj"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="basha"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each>
```

I have a xml something like above. I have to skip the node which doesn't have the `<shaik>` child. I tried by using `xsl:for-each` but I am not able to get the answer.

Comment: I think that you should do `<xsl:if test="not(shaik)">` instead of 
`<xsl:if test="not(node/shaik)">`. Alternatively remove the `xsl:if` completely and filter in the `xsl:for-each` - `<xsl:for-each select="//node[not(shaik)]">`

Comment: Or `<xsl:for-each select="//node[shaik]">` to skip the nodes that don't have a "shaik" child.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) which is used to copy an entire document. From there you can then add "exceptions' where you want to add, remove or skip certain elements.

This XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node[shaik]"/>

<!-- XSLT Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this XML document:

```
<nodes>
    <node>
      <siraj>abc</siraj>
      <shaik>ab</shaik>
      <basha>si</basha>
    </node>
    <node>
      <siraj>abc</siraj>
      <shaik>ab</shaik>
      <basha>si</basha>
    </node>
    <node>
      <siraj>abc</siraj>
      <basha>si</basha>
    </node>
    <node>
      <siraj>abc</siraj>
      <shaik>ab</shaik>
      <basha>si</basha>
    </node>
    <node>
      <siraj>abc</siraj>
      <basha>si</basha>
    </node>
</nodes>
```

Gives this resultant XML:

```
<nodes>
    <node>
        <siraj>abc</siraj>
        <basha>si</basha>
    </node>
    <node>
        <siraj>abc</siraj>
        <basha>si</basha>
    </node>
</nodes>
```